# I don't understand what's wrong with my Pong XNA/C# Code

Tags: c#, xna

I followed this tutorial -

I used the 3rd Method (Polymorphism) to add screens to my game, and now I'm getting errors.

It says it 'Graphics Component not found'

I comment out this code -

```
        ////Vector2 ballPosition = new Vector2(GraphicsDevice.Viewport.TitleSafeArea.X + GraphicsDevice.Viewport.TitleSafeArea.Width / 2,
        ////    GraphicsDevice.Viewport.TitleSafeArea.Y + GraphicsDevice.Viewport.TitleSafeArea.Height / 2);
        //ball.Initialize(Content.Load<Texture2D>("pongball2"), ballPosition);


        ////Vector2 paddle1Position = new Vector2(GraphicsDevice.Viewport.TitleSafeArea.X + GraphicsDevice.Viewport.TitleSafeArea.Width / 100 * 5,
        ////    GraphicsDevice.Viewport.TitleSafeArea.Y + GraphicsDevice.Viewport.TitleSafeArea.Height / 2);
        //paddle1.Initialize(Content.Load<Texture2D>("pongpaddle1"), paddle1Position);

        ////Vector2 paddle2Position = new Vector2(GraphicsDevice.Viewport.TitleSafeArea.X + GraphicsDevice.Viewport.TitleSafeArea.Width / 100 * 99,
        ////    GraphicsDevice.Viewport.TitleSafeArea.Y + GraphicsDevice.Viewport.TitleSafeArea.Height / 2);
        //paddle2.Initialize(Content.Load<Texture2D>("pongpaddle2"), paddle2Position);


        //Score = Content.Load<SpriteFont>("score");
```

And it works, but then after the first screen, it won't progress to the next.

Yeah, I'm stumped here.

Comment: Please remove these screenshots, and add their textual content to your question.  Same with the bin pastes.  External links could go down, text in screenshots and external pages cannot be searched as easily, and SO has nice support for pasting code in your question.

Comment: Does it support me pasting all of it, as I have no idea if the problem is limited to the file that the error message popped up in. If that's a bad idea, what should I paste?

Comment: Try writing out just a few lines of code to repro the problem.  Start with a new project, and add the minimal amount of code to get the line you are having an error on compiling.

Comment: Also, on your error screenshot, it looks like your content (folder?) is named `PongContent` but your `Content.RootDirectory` is set to `"Content"`.  Maybe this is the problem.

Comment: Not sure why it got renamed, as it was like this when I created the project. But it hasn't produced any problems as I've seen this before.

Comment: Can you open the error dialog and extra the whole error message/stack trace you're getting?  Also, now you have too little code... I know you're having trouble figuring out where you problem is, but if you create a brand new project, and start adding tiny snippets of code, I'm sure you'll get to a point where you get this same error.

Comment: @Slateboard you need to edit your question and include at the very least the line of code generating the exception, the type of exception (`ContentLoadException`) and the *full* exception message.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [the constructor for `ContentManager`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb195757.aspx). It takes an `IServiceProvider` parameter.

The content manager uses the service provider to get an `IGraphicsDeviceService`. This service simply provides a `GraphicsDevice` object. Content manager needs a graphics device in order to load textures onto said device.

By default `GraphicsDeviceManager` (which is an `IGraphicsDeviceService`) will register itself with `Game.Services` (which is an `ISeviceProvider`) when you create it in the constructor of *your* game class (which is derived from `Game`).

The `ContentManager` that is provided by `Game.Content` makes use of this same same (`Game.Services`) service provider. So by the time `LoadContent` gets called, it can query the service provider for a graphics device service, from which it can get its graphics device.

The exception you are getting is because the `ContentManager` you are using cannot get a graphics device (or possibly a valid graphics device).

And the reason for this is the **egregious misuse** of the `Game` class. You should only have one. Your `Screen` class is inheriting from `Game`, and so you have several! Don't do that!